# No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Windows.Duration' en 'System.TimeSpan' ¿Alguna solucion?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb.net

Quiero saber la solución a este error:

El código es:

```
tm = mp.NaturalDuration;
lblTiempotranscurrido.Text = tm.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
```

Y el error es:

```
C0029 No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Windows.Duration' en 'System.TimeSpan'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error de conversión implícita se refiere que intentas convertir de forma automática un tipo de dato en otro no compatible.

---

Esto es más entendible si me baso en ejemplos.

-- `Conversión implícita`

```
System.Windows.Duration duration = mp.NaturalDuration;
System.TimeSpan tm               = duration;
```

Esto es, asignar directamente el contenido de una variable con un tipo de dato a otro con un tipo diferente y esperar que el compilador realice la conversión, eso quiere decir `implícito`.

Pero, si ambos tipos no se pueden convertir entre sí, es decir, de [`System.Windows.Duration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.windows.duration?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) a [`System.TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-7.0) o viceversa, obtienes el error [`CS0029`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0029) que indica que la conversión no es posible de esta manera.

-- `conversión explícita`

```
System.Windows.Duration duration = mp.NaturalDuration;
System.TimeSpan tm               = (System.TimeSpan) duration;
```

Nótese `(System.TimeSpan) duration`, que especifica al compilador de forma explícita el valor al que debe intentar convertir, esto quiere decir `explícito`.

Pero esta forma puede fallar, arrojando una [`System.InvalidCastException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.invalidcastexception?view=net-7.0) si tampoco es posible convertir de un tipo a otro de esta manera.

---

Regresando a tu problema, no conozco el tipo `System.Windows.Duration` y por ello, me basaré en https://source.dot.net para echar un vistazo a su código fuente y ver si posee una mejor forma de conversión.

El caso es que sí, la tiene, y se trata de que `System.Windows.Duration` es una estrutura, que presenta una sobrecarga de constructor que recibe un `System.TimeSpan` y también una propiedad `Duration.TimeSpan` que devuelve el `TimeSpan` de este tipo.

Puedes ver el código fuente en que me he basado [en esta entrada](https://source.dot.net/#PresentationCore/System/Windows/Duration.cs,0922b12caaf47091).

Y entonces, sería tan sencillo como:

```
System.Windows.Duration duration = mp.NaturalDuration;
System.TimeSpan tm               = duration.TimeSpan;
lblTiempotranscurrido.Text       = tm.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
```

O, basado en tu código:

```
tm                         = mp.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
lblTiempotranscurrido.Text = tm.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
```

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'No se puede devolver un valor de la propiedad TimeSpan para un valor de Duration de 'Automatic'. Compruebe la propiedad HasTimeSpan antes de solicitar el valor de la propiedad TimeSpan de Duration.'

Comment: @LEON4RDO Parece que debes esperar a que el evento [`MediaOpened`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.mediaopened?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) del reproductor se dispare para tener disponible un valor de duración. ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar tu código del reproductor para ver como lo invocas?

Comment: Hemano! puedes dejarme tu correo o un medio de comunicacion es que la verdad no se del uso de este programa y necesito solucionar eso

Comment: @LEON4RDO Claro!, te pasaré un correo temporal para que me escribas: bofowa3231@razuz.com